Principled Hair BDSF not showing hair
Im just testing out some stuff like different shaders, Im trying out the Principled Hair BDSF but the hairs arent showing up, Im in cycles


The provided blend file contains a sphere with a glass shader. How is this related to the question about hair? Have you uploaded the wrong file?
